# How to predict a random number?

Tags: random, lua

If I know that the seed of random generator is the current unix time:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
```

could I predict what the next result of `math.random` is?

I'm using `math.random` (6) (numbers between 1-6)

and could I create a script that will show me what random numbers will be in like 10 seconds using this logic?

Essentially I want to know if there's a way to recreate `math.random` in Lua and reverse engineer it?

Comment: If you could predict it, it wouldn't be random :-)

Comment: but if they are based on a time which is saved in our PC and everyone has the same time, it is somehow insecure?

Comment: @Sick654 It isn't always the saved time as not everybody uses ```os.time()``` as their seed.

Comment: Also define 'insecure', if you need a secure 100% random number use a true number generator service.

Comment: but, I know they use the os.time() seed >.<

Answer (score 2):

If you know the exact time at which they seed the generator (`os.time()` returns second time, and it has to be EXACTLY the same), and are running Lua on the same platform, then you can simply do:

```
math.randomseed(time_that_you_know)
math.random(6)
```

and your answer will be the same as theirs; that's how pRNGs work.

Comment: thx, but does it really return milisecond time? :| and how can I predict what number will be in +10 seconds? math.randomseed(10) or math.randomseed(0)+10? (they use randomseed from 0)

Comment: @warspyking Sorry, I was thinking of Python. You're absolutely right; this shouldn't be that hard. @Sick654, think about it. `math.randomseed(0) + 10` is `(return value of math.randomseed(0)) + 10`, which is `nil+10`, which is an error.

Comment: so, does it return only seconds and how to foresee what number will be generated after 10 seconds from now? :|

Comment: To get the random number that will be generated by a call to 
    `math.randomseed(os.time())
    math.random(6)`
in ten seconds, do
   `math.randomseed(os.time()+10)
    math.random(6)`